# How to make this code follow Solid Principle C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Currently I have this code:

```
private async Task<(List<SomeModel> data1, List<string> data2)> 
                    ProcessFileAsync(IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesInDirectory)
{
    var data1 = new List<SomeModel>();
    var data2 = new List<string>();
    
    var inDirectory = filesInDirectory as FileInfo[] ?? filesInDirectory.ToArray();
    for (var lIndex = 0; lIndex < inDirectory.Count(); lIndex++)
    {
        var content = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(inDirectory.ElementAt(lIndex).FullName);

        var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inDirectory.ElementAt(lIndex).Name);

        var data1Task = GetData1Async(content, name);
        var data2Task = GetData2Async(content);

        await Task.WhenAll(data1Task, data2Task);

        data1.AddRange(data1Task.Result);
        data2.AddRange(data2Task.Result);
    }

    return (data1, data2);
}
```

The calling code:

```
private async Task<(List<SomeModel> data1, List<string> data2)> BatchProcessFilesAsync()
{
    var batchSize = 4;

    var models
        = await GetDataFromSomewhereAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var listOfRequests = new List<Task<(List<SomeModel> data1, List<string> data2)>>();

    var fileModels = models.ToList();
    for (var skip = 0; skip <= fileModels.Count(); skip += batchSize)
    {
        var files = fileModels.Skip(skip).Take(batchSize);
        listOfRequests.Add(ProcessFileAsync(files));
    }

    // This will run all the calls in parallel to gain some performance
    var allFinishedTasks = await 
    Task.WhenAll(listOfRequests).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The problem I am facing is if I need to add data3 in future, i have to add code here again. Is there a way to make this code Solid.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Note that `GetDataFromSomewhereAsync` and `SomeModel` suggest this is obfuscated code, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you how to review your code from SOLID principles point of view.

Here I try to list some general questions and give some guidance to help you determine that your current solution does violate some of the principles or not.

#### Single - Responsibility principle

Q: What does `XYZ` method do?
If your answer resembles to any of these:

- *First it ... then it ...*
- *It does ... and it ...*
- *It calls ... method and ... method*
- etc.

it is a good sign that your code method does too much things.

Just to make it clear this principle does NOT suggest to wrap each line into a separate function. On the contrary, it suggests to combine those that are closely related to each other to enhance cohesion. We should strive/aim for **high cohesion** and **low coupling**.

#### Open - Closed principle

Q: Is your `XYZ` method suitable for *T* or *W* type of changes?

In this principle you try to guess what will future present you. Let's suppose that `XYZ` can handle `X`, `Y` and `Z`. If you need to support `T` and `W` then do you need to modify the current code or can you for example inherit from that and override only the necessary methods?

#### Liskov Substitution principle

Not applicable here.

#### Interface Segregation principle

Q: Do I (as a consumer of your API) have to know what does each method of `IXYZ` do?

This principle suggests to try to think from the consumer perspective. If I want to call only `X` then do I need an interface which provides `X`, `Y` and `Z`? You can think of this principle as an extension of SRP to interfaces. If your interface contains members that are not highly coherent then you need to slip it.

#### Dependency Inversion principle

Q: Does your `XYZ` class / method depend on other concrete classes?

This principle suggests to depend on abstractions rather than on concrete types. (Remember we are aiming for **loose coupling**). If you depend on abstraction and not the implementation then you can switch easily without the need to modify this class (this helps OCP as well).

---

I hope this helped you a bit. I suggest to further read these excellent articles:

- [What to look for in a Code Review: SOLID Principles](https://blog.jetbrains.com/upsource/2015/08/31/what-to-look-for-in-a-code-review-solid-principles-2/)
- [The Zen of Code Reviews: Review As If You Own the Code](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/the-zen-of-code-reviews-review-as-if-you-own-the-code/)
- [What to look for when reviewing code for SOLID principle ‘violations’](http://davecallan.com/what-to-look-for-when-reviewing-code-for-solid-principle-violations/)